# Why are mirage and visage pronounced differently?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation

Why do we say mirage with an *ah* sound but visage with a *j* sound? I thought it was because of the origin of the word but they both came from French.

Comment: Consider also the words _homage_ and _hommage_, which were borrowed from French at different times.

Comment: Some people don't pronounce them differently.

Answer (score 2):

In French the two seem to have more similar pronunciations. According to Wiktionary, "*[mirage](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mirage)*" is borrowed from French whereas "*[visage](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/visage)*" has come through Middle-English and Anglo-Norman, so one possible explanation is that the former is more recent and the latter has had time to mutate (so to speak).

Comment: ...and, besides, how was *visage* pronounced in 14th century French, anyway?